# android app closed on interruption

Tags: android, interrupt-handling

when my android app is running, i am getting a phone call, either i attend the call or cancel it my app gets closed in background.

I want my app to be running in background.

while i get the phone call in onStop method i am able to see the toast message which i have added

```
@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onStop()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

What should i have to do when the phone call gets finished, i need my app to be opened ?

Here is my code snippet of onResume

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "on Resume being called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

This gets called at time of activity start

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
}
```

What should i have to add in onPause and onResume to get back to my app

Comment: add code snippet of onPause & onResume method.

Answer (score 0):

Use telephony manager to trace phone call status:

```
 public class Main_Activity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TelephonyManager tele = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    PhoneStateListener call = new PhoneStateListener(){
        public void onCallStateChanged (int state , String incomingNumber){
        if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING)
        {
            Log.e ("Phone State" , "_________________Phone is Ringing");
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Ringing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if (state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK)
        {
            Log.e ("Call" , "_________________Phone Call");
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "On Call", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else if (state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE)
        {
            Log.e ("Call" , "_________________No Call");
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Ideal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        }
    };
    tele.listen(call,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}
```

For me it worked perfect.

Comment: thanks, when call completed i am able to get the toast "IDLE", how to call back my app - to the activity where i have stopped earlier

Comment: Try intent when call disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the BroadcastReceiver in order to listen to the phone state. and resume your app whenever the phone call gets finished.
so you should add a PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver

add to the manifest file

```
<receiver android:name=".PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver">
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>     
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver class

```
public class PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
         telephonyManager.listen(new CustomPhoneStateListener(context), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
}
```